# Codeigniter not working on godaddy server

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, post, hosting

I'm having issues with making codeigniter work on godaddy. 
I tried various things but non seemed to work for me. Any help would be appreciated.

my htaccess file is like below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /code-igniter/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

and I already changed my config file:

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php?";

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Please help!!

Comment: the problem is with `index.php`? yout host has `rewrite enabled`?

Comment: Yes rewrite is enabled, what about index.php?

Comment: Why the rewritebase `/code-igniter/` ?? You shouldn't need the question mark at the end of your `index_page`.

Comment: /codeigniter because my path is such as follows:
mydomain.com/codeinginer/folders ... 
So I should put codeigniter no?
Even if I remove the ? from the index_page, it doesnt make a difference

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# If your page resides at
# http://www.example.com/code-igniter/
# then use
# RewriteBase /code-igniter/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**config/config.php**

```
$config['index_page'] = '';    

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately my system is still not running!

Comment: In which directory are your files exists? http://www.example.com or http://www.example.com/foldername/